# Facebook OAuth and redirect URI

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid, openid-connect

Looking at Google OpenId connect and Facebook login I noticed that Facebook always hits the "redirect URI" from the browser. To explain a bit more - when user follows link of the form

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

S/he is always redirected to the URL specified by {redirect-uri}. This URL then contains "code" which can be exchanged for access token.

Google has similar approach but when using "server-flow" the {redirect-uri} is "hit" by Google's servers. This way the code which needs to be exchanged for access token never gets shown to the user.

It seems like FB's approach is less secure as the access code can actually end up in the attacker's hands.

1. Is there a way to have FB send the code to a redirect URI but not actually redirect client? Something like what Google does.
2. Does anyone have a good explanation why FB does not have "server-flow"-like behaviour but only "implicit-flow"?

Comment: _“as the access code can actually end up in the attacker's hands”_ – and where would that be, where would the attacker interfere with the process? And to exchange the code for a token, the app secret is needed as well – where would your attacker get that? If any part of your answer contains “well he hacked my server/my server-side code somehow” – then the other approach, where a script on your server is “hit” by Google’s server, is in no way “safer”.

Comment: Well, this was more hypothetical. In theory an attacker could take a photo of victims screen and, given the screen is large enough, the code would be there. If the attacker is part of some development team, he/she could be part of a development team and have access to secret key. Not very likely to happen but I have seen an attack like this (though not with FB but some other service).

Comment: Once the code has been exchanged for a token by your app, it can not be used a second time … so your attacker would not only need those more than extra-ordinary circumstances you described, he would also have to be very quick … highly unlikely. I think chances of your user simply being forced to give up their credentials at gunpoint would be more likely than this.

Answer (score 3):

You should grab the code from the server then use it, together with your app secret, to exchange an access token on Facebook. It does not matter if the client can see this because without the app secret, that code is useless. And the app secret is kept on your server, it is never revealed to the client.